# Maximize the mutual information between 2 discrete random variables

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, shannon-entropy

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ follows [Poisson-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) distribution with parameters $\{q_1, \ldots, q_k\}$. Thus, $X$ can take values in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,k\}$.

$Y$ is a binary random variable. $Y=0$ with probability $\frac{0.1}{1+i}$ when $X=i$.

I am interested in the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ denoted by $I(X;Y)$.

**Specifically, I have a conjecture that the mutual information $I(X;Y)$
is maximum when all $q_i$'s are equal which leads to a Binomial
distribution for $X$.**

Can someone help me prove this? Or provide a counter example?

Comment: Do you have an intuition or justification for this conjecture?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, First of all, Binomial distribution has the maximum entropy among Poisson- binomial distributions. Also, for a given mean, the variance is maximum when all probability parameters are equal and we have a binomial distribution.

So, I am hoping somehow the symmetry can be used to claim the conjecture. ie, From a Poisson-Binomial, you can always create a BInomial with a better mutual information by mixing the sampling probabilities. I don't know how to establish this though.

Comment: There is a **significant** probability I messed up the "coding" in Mathematica, but, if not, it seems that a version of the conjecture is false (for a given value of $q_1$, it's maximised when all equal) in the case $k=2$: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ccanonne/Published/conjecture-mi-pbd.nb (see the two plots at the end)

Comment: Of course, that may not be what you had in mind (maximised for *some* value of the parameter $(q_1,\dots,q_k)$) where all $q)i$'s are equal, in which case this is not a counterexample (cf. last graph, again, which would support this version))

Comment: @ClementC. I took a look at the plots. Just to make sure, if I understood it correctly; So the maximum mutual information occurs when $q_1 \approx 0.37$ (Last graph). And it seems like the optimal $q_2$ is also around 0.37 (2nd graph)? Am I correct in reading the graphs. If that's true, my conjecture holds, right?

Comment: yes, this is what I laboriously tried to say above. What is *not* true is that, fixing an arbitrary $q_1$, the maximum is for $q_2=q_1$. What might be true (supported by this) is that, optimizing over both $q_1,q_2$, the max is realized for some pair where they are equal.

Comment: @ClementC, Yes, I am interested in joint optimization over all $q_i$'s. This also is in accordance with the intuitions I stated in my first comment. They are all focused on for a given mean $(\sum q_i)$.  So, if someone can prove that for a given mean, my conjecture holds. The extension is trivial.

Comment: Nitpicking: I get what you mean, but I am not so sure the reduction comes with no restriction -- there has to be some restriction (for the statement "without loss of generality, it suffices to prove it for any given mean"). For instance, $\sum_i q_i = k$ or $\sum_i q_i = 0$ are both quite... not general. :)